# How to change select option to radio button and pass the value to model

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I  want to change the select option to the radio button but after the change to radio button, my updated won't work anymore.

Here is a picture for the edit form[image]

I want to change the select option to radio button like it

[image]

After I change to radio button value of inline and offline didn't pass to the database.  I should be the same, I just don't understand, why using select option able to pass the value to the database but radio button can't.
Here is code for radio button

```
   <span>In:</span>
                        <input type="radio" name="inline" value="IN" <?php echo set_radio('inline', 'IN'); ?> />

                        <span>Out:</span>
                     <input type="radio" name="offline" value="OUT" <?php echo set_radio('offline', 'OUT'); ?> />
```

view

```
<div class="col-md-8">
                        <span>In:</span>
                        <select name="online">
                            <option value="IN">Yes</option>
                            <option value="">No</option>
                        </select>
                        <span>Out:</span>
                        <select name="offline">
                            <option value="OUT">Yes</option>
                            <option value="">No</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

controller

```
   public function updateStatu(){
    $this->load->model('Status_Board_Model');
    $value = $this->Status_Board_Model->updateStatu();




    $msg['success']=false;
    $msg['type']='update';
    if($value){
        $msg['success'] = true;
   }

    echo json_encode($value);
}
```

model

```
  public function updateStatu()
{
    $statuid = $this->input->post('statuid');
    $data = array(
        'online' => $this->input->post('online'),
        'offline' => $this->input->post('offline'),
        'comment' => $this->input->post('comment')
    );
    $this->db->where('statuid', $statuid);
    $this->db->update('core.status', $data);
   if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

js

```
--------------save button for edit-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      $('#saveBtn').click(function(e){
            //alert('hello');
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.reload();
            var url = $('#myForm').attr('action');
            //var data = $('#myForm').serialize();
            if(true){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'ajax',
                    method: 'post',
                    url: url,
                    data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
                    datatype: 'json',
                    success: function(){
                        $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                        $('#myForm').get[0].reset();
                        getStatu();
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('Error');
                    }
                });
            }else{
                alert('error');
            }

        });

        $('#info').on('click','.edit',function(){
            var statuid = $(this).attr('data');
            $('#modal_form').modal('show');
            $('#modal_form').find('.modal-title').text('Edit');
            $('#myForm').attr('action', '<?php echo base_url("../Status_Board_Controller/updateStatu") ?>');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'ajax',
                method: 'get',
                url: '<?php echo base_url("../Status_Board_Controller/editStatu") ?>',
                data: {statuid: statuid},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    $('input[name=firstName]').val(data.firstName);
                    $('input[name=online]').val(data.online);
                    $('input[name=offline]').val(data.offline);
                    $('input[name=comment]').val(data.comment);
                    $('input[name=statuid]').val(data.statuid);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Fail to get data');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: i don't get it your html form is an select option not a radio button. coul you please state your main problem?

Comment: How do you call your controller function `updateStatu()` from view? can you share your radio button code so we can know about your mistake?

Comment: I post my JS code.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you included your HTML that works, your HTML that does not work, and any associated javascript for the view.  As it is, if those selects are in a form and you submit the form you'll submit a few combinations for the selects:

```
online=IN&offline=OUT
online=IN&offline=
online=&offline=OUT
online=&offline=
```

Not clear that is what you are doing, or maybe just submitting a change when one of the select option changes ?  You need to explain a little.  Sounds like you would need 2 sets of radio buttons with the names online(2) and offline(2) to simulate what you describe.

Comment: I try pass the value IN or OUT in to database column name inline or offline.

Comment: When I using select option is fine but not radio button

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong input name in your form, it should be `online` instead of `inline` :

```
<span>In:</span>
<input type="radio" name="online" value="IN" <?php echo set_radio('online', 'IN'); ?> />

<span>Out:</span>
<input type="radio" name="offline" value="OUT" <?php echo set_radio('offline', 'OUT'); ?> />
```

And also since you've changed the select into a radio, you should add an empty conditional validation to prevent undefined online/offline post array index on your `updateStatu` model :

```
public function updateStatu()
{
    $statuid = $this->input->post('statuid');
    $data = array(
        'online' => !empty($this->input->post('online')) ? $this->input->post('online') : '',
        'offline' => !empty($this->input->post('offline')) ? $this->input->post('offline') : '',
        'comment' => $this->input->post('comment')
    );
    $this->db->where('statuid', $statuid);
    $this->db->update('core.status', $data);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```